# Disable input based on a condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello all I have the following piece of code:

```
<table class="details-table" *ngIf="peop && peopMetadata">
    <tr *ngFor="let attribute of peopMetadata.Attributes">
        <td class="details-property">{{attribute.AttributeLabel}}</td>
        <td [ngSwitch]="attribute.AttributeType">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'String'">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)] = "peop[attribute.AttributeKey]" />
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchDefault>{{peop[attribute.AttributeKey]}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="">Submit</button>
    </div>
</table>
```

I want to disable the input based on an attribute values say peop[attribute.IsWritable]='false' . How can i achieve this here . Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the form reactive or template-driven?

Comment: template driven

Answer (score 15, accepted):

INPUT only approach:

```
<input [disabled]="!peop[attribute.IsWritable]" matInput [(ngModel)] = "peop[attribute.AttributeKey]" />
```

CONDITIONAL approach:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="peop[attribute.IsWritable]">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="peop[attribute.AttributeKey]" />
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!peop[attribute.IsWritable]">
  <span>{{ peop[attribute.AttributeKey] }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

OR:

```
<input *ngIf="peop[attribute.IsWritable]" matInput [(ngModel)]="peop[attribute.AttributeKey]" />
<span *ngIf="!peop[attribute.IsWritable]">{{ peop[attribute.AttributeKey] }}</span>
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear .What if i don't want it to be an input field itself but just make it a normal display field  based on the condition?

Comment: edited my answer - may not be exactly what you want but should head you in right direction

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This helps a lot .

Comment: Just wanted to know do i have to do the <ng-container ...> for each switch case ? . Is there a way to simplify ?

Comment: you could create a reusable component, passing in the IF condition, and use content projection (you can project multiple bits of content) to supply the relevant HTML for true or false (but i don't think that will reduce the markup much in this case) - alternatively, you could try and create your own strucutral directive (but that could prove a challenge) - see https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive - a structural directive if any directive which can remove / adjust DOM content - e.g. *ngIf

Comment: actually scrap that a much simpler idea, ill update answer - see updated answer

Comment: I tried the following but for some reason the span doesn't seem to work: <input *ngIf="peop[attribute.IsWritable]" matInput [(ngModel)] = "peop[attribute.AttributeKey]" />             
               <span *ngIf="peop[attribute.IsReadable] && !peop[attribute.IsWritable]">{{ peop[attribute.AttributeKey] }}</span>

Comment: you can see values like this <span>{{ peop[attribute.IsWritable] }}</span> - show all your values to help you debug it - it may be a value is not as you expect

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the need to do this and found that I needed to use `ng-disabled` to do it.

```
<input id="my-input-id" class="my-input-class" type="number" name="my-input-name" ng-model="MyCtrl.myModel" required ng-disabled="MyCtrl.myProperty && MyCtrl.myProperty !== 'someValue'"></input>
```

Hope this helps someone else!