# How to disable the input box using the ngIf condition?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

```
<input pInputText type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" *ngIf="pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View] />
```

Above is the input box which I used.. 
My condition:

```
IF(pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View])
{
    -----------(disable the input box)-------------------
}
ELSE
{
    -----------(enable the input box)-------------------
}
```

When I simply use the condition **`pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View]`**, the input box got invisible.

Can anybody help me to disable the input box using  the condition          **`"pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View]"`**

Comment: You need to disable the corresponding FormControl in your TypeScript code: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable

Comment: When I used this, input got invisible.. I need to disable the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable input based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714933/disable-input-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[disabled]="*** your condition ***"` instead. Every html attribute on input elemets can be binded by using `[attribute]`.

In your case this would be:

```
<input pInputText 
    type="text" 
    formControlName="description" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Required" 
    [disabled]="pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View] />
```

You could also use the `formControlName` and set disabled in the controller.

Comment: I have multiple conditions. disable functioning need to work only when the condition, "pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View]"  happens. When I used the condition which you told, it affects to all conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I used [attr.disabled] = "pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View] ? 'disabled' : null".. And now its working

Comment: You're welcome. Together we can learn more so I'm happy to help. 
You shouldn't need to use attr.disabled though. disabled should be enough.
Feel free to accept or upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `*ngIf` and add disabled to your `formControl`:

```
// Whereever you're building your form:
description: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: pageModes[formModel.schema.mode] === pageModes[pageModes.View]})
```

Comment: Can u give me a demo??

Answer (score -1):

add inputDisabled Property into your component

```
export class Component{
   get inputDisabled(){
    return // add your disable logic here 
   }
}
```

set this property to input attribute

```
<input [disabled]="inputDisabled"  .../>
```